# Pra que serve o mappedBy do JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring

**Exemplo:**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "chemical", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
@JsonIgnore
private List<SimulationChemicals> simulationChemicals;
```

**Porque o uso do mappedBy é obrigatório ou importante? não entendi ainda a função dele.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O `mappedBy` é para indicar qual é o lado inverso ou não dominante da relação.

Diferente da annotation `@JoinColumn` que indica que a entidade é a responsável pelo relacionamento.

Ex:

```
public class Endereco {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private long numero;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "endereco") //Endereço não é o lado dominante
    private Pessoa pessoa;

    //getters e setters
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Pode existir relacionamento Unidirecional ou Bidirecional. Quando é unidirecional apenas uma classe tem a referência, que é o atributo, e este é anotado.

```
@Entity
public class SystemUser {
  @OneToOne
  private Debt debt;
}
```

Quando é Bidirecional as duas classe tem um atributo referenciando uma à outra.

```
@Entity
public class SystemUser {
  @OneToOne
  private Debt debt;
}

@Entity
public class Debt {
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(mappedBy = "debt")
  private SystemUser systemUser;
}
```

Adiciona o atributo mappedBy no lado que não é dominante. Na class SystemUser tem um atributo debt, este é o nome que será usado do mappedBy.

Caso não fosse usado o atributo mappedBy, iria ser criado dois relacionamentos entre SystemUser e Debt. Cada relacionamento com um lado dominante.

Tome cuidado com relacionamentos Bidirecionais. Procure mais sobre eles.